# Sharing a project between two solutions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS. I have two solutions. For code-sharing I have referenced the projects of one solution in another solution. However, when the other solution comes to use this project, the settings are different- it has a different toolset and important properties like include paths and such are not set correctly. The original solution, however, seems to be fine.

How can I reference this project so that, well, I end up with the actual project and not just kind of most of it?

Comment: It's a plain C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the first project from solution #1 to 'Static library'. Then add to the used libraries of the second project of solution #2 the `.lib` file of the first project. And add the first project to include path of the second project. So projects will be built independently.

Comment: They are solutions, not projects.

Comment: You say " I have referenced the projects of one solution in another solution". See Update.